# PC with windows 7 block entire network during Update installation

Tags: windows, windows-update, server-crashes

I manage a domain with 80 PC that take the updates from the WSUS on server 2k8 R2, I have set the update to be installed once a week at 14:00 since in this time all the PC are on. Once a 2-3 month during the installation process a random PC is stuck at installation and cause my L2 network to stop.(I mean all the PC connected to that SW loose complete L2 connection, they cant even communicate locally ) I have to check manually all the PC to find this blocking Pc detach from the network, restart the switch so the other PC should be able to reconnect and get back to work.

Does anyone know what kind of updates cause this? Is WSUS involved? And how should I get rid of this annoying, shame problem. The last time I experienced this problem is today. I will attach the list of installed update.

I will be gratefully if anyone can help me solve this situation[image]

Comment: How are you determining that this PC is "stopping" the network? What do you mean the network is stopping? That's a very odd conclusion to come to.

Comment: I have not mentioned that I use un managed-switches. "Network stopping" I mean all the PC connected to that switch's PC loose complete L2 connection, they cant even communicate locally

Comment: in simple words, Switch A in center, topology star. SWA connected with SW1 , SW2 and SW3. PCx on switch SW2 with other 22PC. PCx installing update-- during this process all the network on SW2 is lost. All PC connected on SW2 can't communicate even with each other

Comment: That is a very odd coincidence.  I'd suspect the increased traffic load from WSUS updates might cause the switch to crash or have issues maybe.  You might break up the PCs into separate groups and not update everyone at once.  Maybe do 20% of the PCs on each work day.  Might be prudent not to update everyone at the same time until you iron this out.  My gut says its in the networking hardware though.

Comment: it's driving me crazy, the strongest hypothesis that make me think is a PC failure is because the update are downloaded from time time during a 2 days period starting from monday and than if not installed they will be installed forced by gpo on Wednesday before 2 pm, and the problem is caused on 2:30 pm when some PC where installing those updates, and continue the installation after restart, i think you know the screen ( installing 5/7 updates...)

Answer (score 0):

After one year I found the solution. One day came only one update (delayed) from windows update so I was  able to distinguish from other update, and found 2 PC freezed after have installed Malicious Software Removal tool. I think the problem caused by auto scan that this program do that cause Pc failure and than NIC failure and than all the Broadcast Domain Down.

**EDIT**

This is not a solution because I found that the problem is related on system crash that WMSRT cause a lot of time but it's not directly related to this software

[image]

I have seen the 2 freezed PC and they have the log on : C:\WINDOWS\Debug\MRT.log   unfinished so the only 2 PC that freeze have logged only the "Started On" and didn't make it for the result. All the other PC on the domain have the result summary for March. I don't know what cause this by I Declined MRT from WSUS, I have no choice and am really tired of this. The forums said that will be by a conflict with antivirus but I use MSE on all PC so theoretically doesn't have to conflict. 
I hope this post be helpful for anyone in this circumstances.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool v5.21, February 2015 (build 5.21.11102.0)
Started On Wed Feb 11 12:24:58 2015

Engine: 1.1.11302.0
Signatures: 1.191.3593.0

Results Summary:
----------------
No infection found.
Failed to submit clean hearbeat MAPS report: 0x80072EFD
Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool Finished On Wed Feb 11 12:41:10 2015


Return code: 0 (0x0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool v5.22, March 2015 (build 5.22.11202.0)
Started On Tue Mar 10 16:12:29 2015

Engine: 1.1.11400.0
Signatures: 1.193.1181.0
```